# Can change network architecture during training in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to change channel dimensions of convolution layer during training, but in testing, always keeping same dimensions.
I tried to implement this in tensorflow, and i failed. 
If the output dimension changes during training, an error occurs because the tensor flow does not recognize the changed graph.
Does not the tensor flow implement these features?
If not, is there any other way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the number of channels of a convolution layer on the fly as it would basically amount to having a new network with a different structure, different number of weights, etc.

The convolution weights are represented by a matrix `A` of shape `(k, k, cout, cin)` for a convolution with a `k`x`k` kernel with `cin` input channels and `cout` ouput channels. Changing the number of channels would change the shape of the matrix `A`.

There are a few hacks you could do like padding the channel dimension. Another solution could be to have your network fork where you need a variable channel dimension before merging back (if possible) but this would induce an increase in learnable parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. yes, i also tried to padding instead of drop.  but if i padding with zero, test loss & accuracy were madly increased. In this case, i used zeros matrix, not tf.Variable. 
ex) y = tf.layers.conv2d(),     y = tf.concat(y, tf.zeros))
Could this possibly cause an increase in the error rate?
If so, can I mitigate this by changing the zero matrix to tf.variable with initialized zero?

Comment: Padding with zeros can have multiple unintended effects. After the kernel is multiplied with a patch of the input, the output value at a given position is the sum across all channels, thus, the range of the output values will highly depend on the number of channel. You should pad your input carefully. For instance, you could pad every additional channel with the mean of the given channel on the training data that possess this particular channel instead of zeros ; the idea here being to pad with as uninformative data as possible but without affecting the ranges.

Comment: I really really thank you. You make me to enlighten some things that i overlook about this problem. I understand your comment!! Although my english is not enough, you helped me very kindly. I'm grateful for you.
I have last question. 
In the above answer, when I connected the weighted matrices filled with zeros, the learning proceeded normally, but the problem of a sudden increase in error rate occurred only in the test. How can I this be interpreted?

Comment: At that time I used the following conditional statement.
tf.cond(training, 
lambda : tf.concat(x, tf.zeros),
lambda : tf.concat(x, y))  
(x is overall channel list, y is result of conv layer)